# Jenkins pipeline stage view build unstable but show red

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

[stage view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFRvJ.png)

6 build - failed, shown in red
7 build - unstable, also shown in red and columns are empty

Comment: did it actually manage to progress enough to get into stage 1? or did it fail/become unstable before starting stage 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's bug

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43556 - Stage View shows incorrect build result

Answer (score 0):

when checking the cache, the FlowNodeUtil cache RunExt was failure instead of success,
What solved the issue for me was restarting Jenkins (But this is just a workaround.).

**Jenkins version is:** 2.176.1
[image]